# Linkedin Ads API doesn't provide industry data correctly

Tags: linkedin-api, social-networking, social-media, ads-api

I was trying to get data from industry linkedin ads API. (version March 2023) `202303`
Using this endpoint

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/industries?ids={id1}&ids={id2}&ids={id3}
```

The response structure is

```
{'result': [], 'errors': []}
```

The object in result is good, But object in `errors` is

```
{'1187': {'message': 'Could not find standard industry for industry id: 1187}, 'status':404}
...
```

Then I try to find solution for this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/reference-tables/industry-codes-v2
I found at `ActiveNodes`

```
1187 Wholesale Machinery
```

This 1187 still valid in active node. But it's doesn't return data from API.

So now i wonder why `1187` and some of industry ids couldn't return response.
It's still in ActiveNodes.

Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this the above API docs. It's cover only parent urn ID.
That couldn't find or search any child ids.

If you want get data from the ids (in this case id value > 150)
you might found this from this resource

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/industrytaxonomyversions